# .Net Routing for links

Tags: .net, vb.net, routes

I am trying to work with routing on a site I am creating. If I have two routes, `/Home/{Value1}/default.aspx` for route 1 and `/Users/{Value2}/default.aspx` for route 2, how do I tell a link I am creating to use a specific route. I am trying to create links in my .vb code behind pages but I am unsure on how to tell it to use either route 1 or route 2 depending on my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are mapping a route, you can give it a name. If you're using the HtmlHelper to build Action links then you can tell it what named route you want the link to use.

```
routes.MapRoute("Route1",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}");

routes.MapRoute("Route2",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}");
```

Then the HtmlHelper in your view, use the [RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470133.aspx):

```
@Html.RouteLink("Click Me", "Route2", new { id = "whatever" })
```